# How to pass array of objects to partialo in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js

I need to pass parameter to a partial. This parameter is array that contains objects. Unfortunately I'm not able to get value from that parameter. It's doesn't throw any error, but it creates elements without values.
In template I have:

```
{{> _partials/breadcrumb.html data='["breadcrumbs.home", "breadcrumbs.blog"]' }}
```

In json file I have these data:

```
{
"breadcrumbs": {
    "home": {
      "url": "/",
      "title": "Home"
    },
    "blog": {
      "url": "/blog.html",
      "title": "Blog"
    }
}
```

And partial creates breadcrumbs like these:

```
<nav class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="breadcrumbs-list">
        {{#each (getJsonContext data) }}
        <li>
            <a href="">{{'title'}}</a>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

getJsonContext it's a helper that converts jSON string to object

```
export default function(data) {
  return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Project uses HTMLWebpackPlugin 4.0.0-beta.5 and Handlebars 4.7.6